# Adding Stripe Pod- linker error

Tags: ios, swift, linker, cocoapods, stripe-payments

The pod was installed properly. I also tried a clean/build multiple times. My header files are included in the bridging header.
My architectures include arm64 but I'm still receiving this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
 __TMaCSo6Stripe in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually when I ran pod install, it didn't inherit my path in

```
 OTHER LINKER FLAGS
```

so it was a manual fix by adding

```
$(inherited)
```

Hope this helps someone if they encounter the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Daisy, was facing same issue, Just fixed by adding $(inherited)

Comment: No problem this is surely cocoapods hell

Answer (score 0):

I just integrated the Stripe cocoapod yesterday and had quite a few issues myself. I'm guessing in your Stripe/Support Files in your Pods directory, you have a file called `Stripe-umbrella.h`.

The only luck I had integrating Stripe was importing the umbrella file in my bridging header like below (make sure to remove quotes):

```
#import <Stripe/Stripe-umbrella.h>
```

Add this, clean, build and you should have better luck.

For the record, I'm using XCode7.

Comment: Did you use any specific version of Stripe? I don't have that file Stripe-umbrella.h under Stripe/Support Files

Comment: no specific version was specified in my podfile. All I did was just a **pod 'Stripe'** in my Podfile. When you open your project via the .xcworkspace file, you'll be able to see your Pods directory and from there, Stripe should be included with a Support Files folder and the umbrella file.

Comment: ah I didn't see your mention about Xcode7. I am using 6.4